# setup liferay with external db

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm using liferay 6.2 and we have a requirement that the application server must be in one VM and the database associated with it must be in different VM, so for this in portal-setup-wizard.properties file in this line:

```html
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false

is modified by below line

jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://serverhostname:3306/databasename?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
```

is this the right way to achieve the above mentioned requirement, or any other changes is required? please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: This is correct but also make sure you also put accurate user and password information.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You must set up the next properties in your custom "portal-ext.properties":

#### MySQL sample

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useFastDateParsing=false
jdbc.default.username=username
jdbc.default.password=password
```

You have more information about jdbc properties here:

```
https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/propertiesdoc/portal.properties.html#JDBC
```

Comment: hi the above mentioned content is added in portal-ext.properties file but my application in not able to connect to mysql database. please help how the above requirement can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

**Liferay -> portal-ext.properties**

```
jdbc.default.jndi.name=jdbc/LiferayPool
```

**Tomcat -> server.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/LiferayPool"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://10.128.1.54:3306/x"
    username="x"
    password="x"
   maxActive="20"
   maxIdle="20"
   initialSize="20"
   minIdle="10"
   maxWait="30000"
   testOnBorrow="true"
   testOnReturn="false"
   testWhileIdle="true"
   validationQuery="SELECT 1"
   validationQueryTimeout="10"
   timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
   minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
   removeAbandoned="true"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
   validationInterval = "30000"
   maxAge = "0" />
```

Comment: Hi as suggested the above two changes were made in portal-ext.properties and Tomcat -> server.xml but my liferay application is unable to connect to mysql database which is located on different server. please help

Comment: The log that tells you? Be careful, I would lower my liferay and reconfigure it from 0 ... @HeenaRamesh

Comment: hi , please suggest solution for above request

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved rather simply actually. You do not need to do this in `portal-ext.properties` or `portal.properties.`

do it in the `portal-setup-wizard.properties` and change this property `jdbc.default.url=` to your DB instance that you want.

Hope this helps!